# After playing HTML5 video, status bar white space remains

Tags: iphone, ios, html

This problem appears similar to other posts, it is not the same as any I can find.

My application has "NO" status bar, it uses a tab bar controller and each tab has a navigation controller. There is nothing special about any of these controllers, all per Apple's guidelines.

When a video is selected a view is pushed onto the stack and shows information about the video and a UIWebView with HTML5 and the Video (+ViewPort) tags. The video goes full screen, if you tap the video and hit done, you return to the view without any issues.

If you rotate the device while the video is playing, then tap and select Done you are returned to the view but the 20px status bar remains as white space. No events are fired anywhere when the video quits so I have not been able to resize the view.

(just an FYI, I tried making the app use a StatusBar, the result was a chopped off view when the video quit under the same conditions)

Any ideas would be great, thanks.

Comment: fyi - I have logged this as a bug in iOS and Apple are looking into it. It is easily reproducible in a very simple project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been confirmed by Apple as a bug and will be fixed in a future release. I opened the bug with ID 9251792 if anyone needs a reference.